# CSS adding automating number for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that i want to add automatic number for each row. I want the to appear on the second column.

This must be a straight forward thing to do, but just couldn't figure it out.i have follow the direction from [Automatic Serial Number Row in HTML Table](http://mariusmateoc.com/blog/automatic-serial-number-row-in-html-table/)

but this only appear on the first column. i want that to appear on the second td:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then use `:nth-child` psuedo selector, or you can use javascript to iterate over the rows and add the number to one of the cells.  Both options are below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach(function(table) {
    var index = 1;
    table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(row) {
        row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(column, position) {
            if (position === 1) {
                column.innerHTML = '' + index;
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
table{
  counter-reset: serial-number;  /* Set the serial number counter to 0 */
}

tr td:nth-child(3):before {
  counter-increment: serial-number;  /* Increment the serial number counter */
  content: counter(serial-number);  /* Display the counter */
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>D</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>F</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>G</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: When i convert html table to  an excel file the numbers doesn't seem to appear. any idea how this could be accomplished

Comment: still it doesn't display the row number when converted to excel

Comment: how are you converting to excel?

Comment: i convert the table using java script

Comment: create a jsfiddle.  "using javascript" doesn't give me very much to work with